# react-native-track-player crashing due to exo player version conflict in track-player and react-native-video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video, react-native-track-player

So I am using react-native-video and react-native-track-player  parallelly, Normally both are working fine, but to use some extra functionalities of video player like buffering I have to use Exo player  , but using exo player manually is making react-native-track player crash well i was trying to get an answer and find that it was happening due to conflict in exo player versions used by both libs. can anyone help

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem background

Both [react-native-track-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player) and [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) are built on top of the [Exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/) (the application level media player for android).

In the current versions of react-native-track-player and the react-native-video the following exoplayer versions are used:

- **react-native-track-player (2.1.3):**
  *node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\build.gradle*

  ```
   dependencies {
       ...   
       def exoPlayerVersion = safeExtGet("exoPlayerVersion", '2.11.4')
       ...
   }
  ```
- **react-native-video (5.2.0):**
  *node_modules\react-native-video\android-exoplayer\build.gradle*

  ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.2') {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support'
       }
       ...
       implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.13.2') 
       {
           exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
       }
       ...
   }
  ```

As you can see both require different versions of the exoplayer which causes the problem (application crash).

## Solution

The available solution is to make sure both packages use the same version of exoplayer. We can achieve this by **downgrading one of the packages until it matches the exoplayer version of the other**. Since current version react-native-track-player uses the older version of exoplayer (2.11.4) we have no option but to downgrade react-native-video down to the version which use exoplayer 2.11.4 which is the version 5.1.1.

Therefore the problem will be solved if you **downgrade the react-native-video down to 5.1.1**.

```
npm i react-native-video@5.1.1
```

***Note:*** This may cause some minor issues in react-native-video. (ex: `textTracks` property of `Video` class might not work)

Comment: Is there any error message? (in android debugger or react native debugger)

Comment: no , it is breaking some working functionalities of my video player which i cannot afford.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a long time ago, but it might help someone,
I had the same problem, solved using the 'patch-package'

https://gist.github.com/Fairbrook/53127f8a05c020836a64f6c19b71f889#file-react-native-track-player-2-1-2-patch

to use is simple 
1 - npm i patch-package 
2 - Create folder in the project root with name 'patches' 
3 - Create a file named 'react-native-track-player+2.1.2.patch'
4 - Copy the code from the link and paste it in the file
5 - npm install

This should solve it, solve it for me

Comment: I  visited the link , it is working for others i don't know why this solution is not working for me, May be i am doing something wrong .     I am using react-native-video@5.2.0 & react-native-track-player@2.1.3 ,
everything working fine till i decided to use exoplayer for react native video,
I added this dependency in react-native.config.js
"
'react-native-video': {
platforms: {
android: {
sourceDir:
'../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
},
},
},
"
after this app is crashing whem i am opening audio player.

Comment: could you help me i am new in development.